# file format for generating model for Blender

Tags: 3d, blender

I have an application which manage a warehouse (dealing with shelves and boxes) and I need to export it to blender. What is the easiest format to generate 3D models compatible with blender ? I don't need anything fancy, just to export facets, colors and eventually group them hierarchically.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at Wavefront or collada format and it appears that in my situation, generating a python script building the required scene was the easiest.